# Is there a way of copy docker image into host docker images location rather than create a repository?

Tags: docker

I use Dockerfile created a docker image named alphine-test:

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alphine-test        v1.0                6837c85a8b1b        5 days ago          4.15MB
```

now I have some questions about it:

docker image seems store use levels. there is not a constant location to store an image like a file.
so there is a way for providing source by build own docker repository. then pull the repo from it.

but whether there is other way to provide images like copy a vm's image, such as `centos8.2`'s OS image(this is a vm OS file, not docker image).

because use this way is convenient and do not need to create a repository and push/pull images.

Comment: Would `docker pull IMAGE:TAG` not work? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the question, it seems like that would do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker image save -o foo.tar alphine-test:v1.0
```

And

```
docker image load -i foo.tar
```